# global variable is giving back undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, undefined, global

in node js i have this code

```
const scraper = () => axios.get("https://thehackernews.com/").then((urlData) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(urlData.data)
  videoTitle = $(".home-title")
})

console.log("logging to the console:", videoTitle)


client.messages
  .create({
    body: `Message: ${videoTitle}`,
    
    
  })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid))
  .done();
```

im trying so what ever is scraped from the website using videoTitle is going to go into the body for the messages, but it keeps saying undefined

Comment: You have to put `client.messages.create` and `console.log` into your `then`, or put them into a function called by `then` so that the promise resolves before you try to use them. Sync code doesn't pause and wait for async code to complete--that's the whole point of async.

Comment: This will be sort of dirty since someone closed the question but here is a bit of code that you could try: `import axios from "axios";
import cheerio from "cheerio";

axios
  .get("https://thehackernews.com/")
  .then((urlData) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(urlData.data);
    const videoTitle = $(".home-title");

    return videoTitle.text();
  })
  .then((videoTitle) => {
    console.log("logging to the console:", videoTitle);

    // ... client.messages code here
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message || error);
  });`